# PHPStorm Regex Replace with back calls

Tags: regex, replace, phpstorm

I want to use PHPStorm to find and replace all instances of:

```
[A-z]['][s]
```

---

Example:

`Andy's` or `David's`

to:

`Andy\'s` or `David\'s`

I have the regex as above, but I want to know how to use the found character in the regex in the replace.

Comment: keep in mind that the range `A-z` isn't equivalent to `A-Za-z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the regex the way you have it:
`[A-z]['][s]`

You can't use a shortcut `[A-z]` to get a range of all upper and lower. You need to use `[A-Za-z]`. You also don't need the apostrophe and s in brackets:

`[A-Za-z]'s`

Then, to replace with a matched group, use $ groups:

`([A-Za-z])'s`, replacing with `$01\\\\'s`

Answer (score 0):

The `$` character is used to access the array of regex groups.

The regex groups can be defined with brackets.

This works:

Find: `([A-z/0-9])['][s]`

Replace: `$01\\\\'s`

---

(To print one slash, 4 are needed.)